Linear inqualities: choice problem
Let's say I have two finite sequences of non-empty real intervals $[a_i, A_i]$, $[b_i, B_i]$ indexed by $1\leq i \leq n$ and a pair of numbers $c < C$. Moreover I have the following condition: interval
$$
E = [\max\limits_i(a_i - B_i + i) - C, \min\limits_i(A_i - b_i + i) - c]
$$
is non-empty.
I'm trying to prove that there exist $x_i\in [a_i, A_i]$, $y_i \in[b_i, B_i]$, $z\in [c, C]$ and $\varepsilon \in E$ such that $x_i - y_i = z + \varepsilon - i$ for all i. Ideally, this proof is constructive in a sense that it describes the set of all possible solutions.
Any help is appreciated. The problem seemed simple, but my first attempts at it failed and I am not even sure where to look for relevant solution methods. It reminds me a bit of linear programming a bit, hence I've put the optimization tag.
Edit: the answer holds in a more restricted case when $[\max\limits_i(a_i - B_i + i), \min\limits_i(A_i - b_i + i)]$ is non-empty per se, which happens to be enough for my considerations.

Define $$\alpha:=\max_i(a_i-B_i+i)\quad\text{and}\quad\beta:=\min_i(A_i-b_i+i).$$
With the notations
$$\begin{align}U+V&:=\{u+v\mid u\in U,v\in V\}\\U-V&:=\{u-v\mid u\in U,v\in V\},\end{align}$$
first note that
$$I:=[c,C]+E=[c,C]+[\alpha-C,\beta-c]=[\alpha-\eta,\beta+\eta]$$
where $\eta:=C-c>0$.
There exists a solution iff this interval $I$ meets
$$J:=\bigcap_i\left([a_i,A_i]-[b_i,B_i]+i\right)=\bigcap_i\left[a_i-B_i+i,A_i-b_i+i\right]$$
A necessary and sufficient condition for this is $J\ne\varnothing$, i.e. $\alpha\le\beta$ ($J$ is then equal to $[\alpha,\beta]\subset I$).

By $[\alpha,\beta]-[c,C]$ do you mean ${(\gamma-z):\gamma\in [\alpha,\beta], z\in[c,C]}$? Notation seems familiar, but I am not experienced with it. Is it an obvious fact that $E$ can be decomposed in such a way, or should this be proved separately

thanks. Any specific area of math covers such problems? Seems closest to real analysis (e.g. the only time I saw this notation is about differences of elements of the Cantor set being the interval), but in all of my encounters with it I have never faced anything similar.

I don't know. As you can see, it uses nearly nothing. P.S. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Interval_operators

Seems useful. If I understand your answer correctly, we have a free choice over $\gamma$ and $z$ in the relevant intervals. Moreover, $x_i, y_i$ are only related to $\gamma$ and are completely independent of $z$. So if reparametrize $\varepsilon$ via $\gamma-z$ then the solution space can be represented by $[c,C]\times \Phi$ where projection of $\Phi$ onto $\gamma$ axis is $[\alpha, \beta]$.

I've meant that if $\Psi \subseteq \Bbb R^{2+2n}$ are all combinations of $(z, \gamma, x_1, y_1, \dots, x_n, y_n)$ that satisfy the desired conditions, then $\Gamma = [c, C]\times \Phi$ and projection of $\Phi$ on its first coordinate is $[\alpha, \beta]$. Thanks for the help in realizing this as characterizing the solution set was also of interest to me. I've double checked your answer this morning, and accepting it.

Let me check the latter, perhaps I operate under more restrictive assumptions without realizing it.
